# PHP detect if page is reloaded with PHP_SELF

Tags: php, self, referer

I have a form that reloads the page with the updated data:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update data">
</form>
```

When the page is updated I want to display a message "Data updated". There was something like this with **Referer** I beleve, but can't remember.

btw I am also using:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // prevent resending data
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

to avoid the annoying resending data message when the user clicks the back button. Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need to set the action attribute on your form. A form is submitted to itself by default.

Comment: So <form name="form" method="post"> will do?? Sweet!

Comment: Yep. But if you're using a HTML4 or XHTML doctype and you want your HTML to validate you need to keep the attribute in. `action=""` will do. With an HTML5 doctype you can leave it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely sure that a form was submitted, you can store a variable in a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();      // at top of page
...
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = true;
    ...
    // prevent resending data
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
elseif ($_SESSION['form_submitted'])
{
    ...
}
```

Less reliable but also possible is the use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to detect what page the visitor came from.

Comment: I'd say checking the referrer is good enough if it's just to show an informational message.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Something like: if (basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) echo "data updated"; Will do the trick for now than? I am not to much concerned about security as this page is behind a login sysytem.

Comment: @FFish: Something like that should do it. Note however that if people can click on a link to the same page, they will also get that message (like clicking on Contact on the Contact page).

Comment: As jeroen says, you just need to set $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = false; inside the elseif block, to prevent it remaining set for the whole session.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this ...

a. redirect to self, but with an extra piece of information - "?updated=true" (or **&**updated=true if PHP_SELF already contains a query string)

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // prevent resending data
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?updated=true');
}
```

b. Based on this extra information, display the text.

```
if (isset($_GET['updated'])) {
    echo "data updated";
}
```

... and yes, your redirect is a valid way to prevent resubmision

Comment: thanks but I have already a var in there like: admin/photos-edit.php?ref=002140 and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: ok, so you can add '&updated=true' instead (ampersand instead of question mark). You'd end up with admin/photos-edit.php?ref=002140&updated=true

Comment: yeah I know, it's a good solution but I want to keep the url clean like that. thnx anyway

Answer (score 1):

A generally accepted way to prevent the "resend data" message is to use the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Ideally you shouldn't be using the same page to display results and also process the form. I would suggest moving "Data updated" to a separate page that you redirect to after the form validation has passed.

This way, the Back button on the browser behaves intuitively for the user without those annoying messages.

Also, technically the $_SERVER "referer" value can be spoofed so you shouldn't always rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use what you're using pretty much:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "data submitted";
}
```

Why not do that?

Comment: Because he's doing a redirect there and needs to show the "Data updated" after that redirect.

Comment: Oh, mis-understood.  Thanks mercator, it's nice when people help more than just the people asking the question, SO is a great community.